# Regex match clear single punctuation + reduce consecutive punctuation

Tags: python, regex, python-3.5

I am trying to use regex to remove 'solo' (predefined) punctuation marks and remove consecutive punctiation marks:

"ews by almalki : Tornado, flood deaths reach 18 in U.s., more storms ahead"

to

"ews by almalki Tornado flood deaths reach 18 in U.s. more storms ahead"

Thus removing the ":" because it is not contained within a word, but keeping the "." in U.s. as in is contained within a word. However the "," after u.s. should also be removed because it is a second consecutive punctuation mark.

So far I have the following code to remove consecutive punctation marks:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'([.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-])[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]+')
n = r.sub(r'\1', "ews by almalki : Tornado, flood deaths reach 18 in U.s., more storms ahead ")
print(n)
```

Comment: Is it Python 3.5+?

Comment: Yes, it is python 3.5. Updated the tag accordingly

Comment: Well, it is not quite clear but if the solution below starts working weird, you may try defining a punct block `pclass = '[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_\`~()-]'` and then build the pattern as `r = re.compile(r'({0}){0}+|(?<=\s){0}(?=\s)'.format(pclass))`. The `(?<=\s){0}(?=\s)` part will only match a single punctuation symbol that is enclosed with whitespaces.

Comment: If you prefer my solution, please let know, I will post with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

change your regex pattern to this should fix it

```
r = re.compile(r'([\s.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-])[.,/#!$%^&*;:{}=_`~()-]+')
```